# Problema com selenium em python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Fiz um programa para fazer o download de 64 faturas, ele vai bem até a nona, mas quando chega nela o selenium para de clicar sem apresentar erro

todos os elif pegam um id diferente e executam a mesma ação com ele, mas quando chega no nono elif ele trava, mas se eu começo direto do 9 ele funciona e trava no 17, gostaria de saber pq trava de 9 em 9

Ele para nesse trecho do código:

```
segunda_via = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="card-vertical-align ng-scope"]')
    segunda_via.click()
    #sleep(10)
```

e esse é o resto do código, tendo 63 elif entre o primeiro if e o else, travando apenas no nono:

while a < 64:
        #Mudar Opções do driver do chrome
        chrome_options = Options()
        #localização dos donwloads
        download_dir = "C:\scrapy"

```
    #Novas configurações
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
        "download": {
        "prompt_for_download": False,
        "default_directory"  : download_dir
        }
    })
    #Localizar webdriver no pc e entrar no site
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\scrapy\chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://servicosonline.cpfl.com.br/agencia-webapp/#/login')
    sleep(15)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 600).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'encontrarInstalacao')))
    #Clicar no checkbox do email
    email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@translate="@APP-COMMON-EMAIL"]')
    email.click()

    #Digitar email
    username = driver.find_element_by_id('documentoEmail')
    username.send_keys('email')
    sleep(0.5)

    #Digitar Senha
    password = driver.find_element_by_id('senha')
    password.send_keys('password')
    sleep(0.5)

    #Clicar botao para logar
    sign_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@valeutype="submit"]')
    sign_in_button.click()
    sleep(2)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'selInstalacao')))

    #Localizar botão Para procurar unidade
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="search"]')
    search_button.click()
    sleep(0.5)

    #Achar Unidades
    if a == 1:

        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.send_keys('25805681') # Pressionar o C
        actions.perform()

        teste = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope active"]')
        teste.click()
        sleep(1)
     elif a == 9:      

    #trocar nome e pasta do arquivo
    os.rename('C:/scrapy/' + 'conta-completa.pdf','C:/scrapy/teste/' + '38085143.pdf')
    #trocar nome de arquivos da pasta
    original_dir = 'C:/scrapy/teste'
    for n, file_name in enumerate(os.listdir(original_dir), 1):
        full_path = os.path.join(original_dir, file_name)
        if (os.path.isfile(full_path) and '{}_'.format(n) not in file_name):
            os.rename(full_path, '{}/{}_{}'.format(original_dir, n, file_name))

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys('39615529')
    actions.perform()

    teste = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope active"]')
    teste.click()
    sleep(1)

... goes to elif 64
else:      

        #trocar nome e pasta do arquivo
        os.rename('C:/scrapy/' + 'conta-completa.pdf','C:/scrapy/teste/' + '4001760792.pdf')
        #trocar nome de arquivos da pasta
        original_dir = 'C:/scrapy/teste'
        for n, file_name in enumerate(os.listdir(original_dir), 1):
            full_path = os.path.join(original_dir, file_name)
            if (os.path.isfile(full_path) and '{}_'.format(n) not in file_name):
                os.rename(full_path, '{}/{}_{}'.format(original_dir, n, file_name))
        sleep(2)


    #Clicar no acessar
    acessar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block ng-scope"]')
    acessar.click()
    sleep(4)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnPagar')))

    #Clicar Botão Segunda Via
    segunda_via = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="card-vertical-align ng-scope"]')
    segunda_via.click()
    #sleep(10)

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'debitosPendentes')))
    pdf = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-segunda-via-aberta ng-scope"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pdf[0])
    sleep(2)

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnVerContaCompleta')))  
    conta_completa = driver.find_element_by_id('btnVerContaCompleta')
    conta_completa.click()
    sleep(20)
    a = a + 1
    print ('Todas faturas Baixadas')
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Provavelmente nesse momento o elemento deixa de ser clicável. Tente usar um `try catch`

Comment: como seria esse try catch?

Comment: Não entendi para que servem 64 `elif`s!! Não dava pra fazer tudo junto?? Coloque o código de mais `elif`s, **principalmente**, do nono `elif` que você disse que é onde está parando.

Comment: alterei, todos os 64 são iguais ao 9

Comment: Se todos são iguais, para que eles existem??

Comment: tem uma lista de 64 ids, cada elif pega um id e renomeia ele, todos os elifs fazem a mesma coisa, mas um para cada id, problema que ele roda os 8 primeiros, no 9 ele trava, mas se eu colocar para começar direto do 9 ele vai, e trava no 17, gostaria de entender o pq ele trava de 9 em 9

Comment: ao invés de 64 `elif`s, faça uma `lista_de_ids` e use um `for id_atual in lista_de_ids:` aí dentro do for você coloca o código, usando essa variável `id_atual` pra renomear. Assim não é preciso repetir o código

Comment: quanto ao travamento de 9 em 9, provavelmente está relacionado com a página. Será que a página não é do tipo que tem elementos que carregam dinamicamente à medida que o usuário vai rolando?

Comment: descobri o erro, a pagina estava sem fatura e ele tentava baixar mesmo assim